# Excel Button Issues

Tags: excel, vba

I made a very simple macro that adds a column to the end of table with concatenated values, there is no issue when i click on the vba button.[image]

However an issue arises when I assign a macro to the button on a separate workbook, it fails to fill all the rows with the correct values. (See black circle on Image)
[image]

My code is below

```
  sub OrganizingResearchTracker()
    
    'Variables
    Dim lr As Long
    lr = Cells.Find("*", Cells(1, 1), xlFormulas, xlPart, xlByRows, xlPrevious, False).Row
    
    Dim tbl As ListObject
    Dim wbNames As Variant, wb As Workbook, w As Workbook, El As Variant, boolFound As Boolean
    
      wbNames = Split("January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,September,October,November,December", ",")
      For Each w In Workbooks
        For Each El In wbNames
            If w.Name = "Completed Research Docs_Tracker_" & El & " 2020.xlsm" Then
                Set wb = w: boolFound = True: Exit For
            End If
        Next
        If boolFound Then Exit For 'in order to stop iteration if a lot of workbooks are open
         Next
    
    '1. Column AB - Descriptive Field - Client Name - Manager Name - Research Deliverable
    
    wb.Activate
    Set tbl = ActiveSheet.ListObjects("Table_owssvr")
    With tbl
            .ListColumns.Add.Name = "Client Name - Manager Name - Research Deliverable"
    End With
    
        Range("AB2:AB" & lr).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-22],"" - "",RC[-26],"" - "",RC[-15])"
end sub
```

Anyone had this issue and know how to amend it? thank you

Comment: Try `.ListColumns("Client Name - Manager Name - Research Deliverable").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = ...`, inside the `With tbl`.

Comment: @BigBen do you know why the buttons struggle with this?

Comment: I'm guessing `lr` is not what you expect it is.

Comment: but it works on the normal code just not when I assign a button, strange

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It'd be easier to just write the formula to the `.DataBodyRange` of the `ListColumn` you created.

```vb
With tbl
    ...
    .ListColumns("Client Name - Manager Name - Research Deliverable").DataBodyRange.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=CONCATENATE(RC[-22],"" - "",RC[-26],"" - "",RC[-15])"
End With
```